# NumberFormatException in InputString

Tags: java, parsing, long-integer, numberformatexception

Please help me solve this exception:-

```
String strBinary="100000000000000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000";
        System.out.println("length is " + strBinary.length()); 
        long intParse=Long.parseLong(strBinary, 2);
        System.out.println("int parsed is " +   intParse); 
        String hexString=Long.toHexString(intParse);
          System.out.println(hexString);
```

Output is 72 along with NumberFormatException while parsing using Long.parseLong..
But till yesterday it was running absolutely fine for this input also..
does it have anything to do with the length...
I am actuallly trying to convert String into its equivalent Hex value.

Please help....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `long` can hold 64 bit of data. The biggest value a `long` can represent is 9223372036854775807 (or 2<sup>63</sup>-1). The string you try to parse is *a lot larger* than that.

You *might* be able to go somewhere by using the [`BigInteger`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) class, which can handle arbitrary-sized integer values (effectively restricted by memory, of course).

Comment: But how do I then parse my incoming String..I have a string and I want to find the hexadecimal equivalent of that.

Comment: @ankit: please take a few minutes to read the link I posted and try to search for the answer on the web. If you still have questions *after that*, feel free to ask.

Comment: i guess using longValue i can convert BigInt to long but my incoming string is first parsed into Long...While parsing it is throwing error..

Comment: @ankit: you **can't** parse that `String` into a `long` because it's too large a number to *fit* into a `long`. You need to go *directly* from `String` to `BigInteger` *or* find another approach.

Comment: @ankit you don't need `long` at all, if you use `BigInteger` in this case.

Comment: Morever incoming input is String of 72 bits length.Now how can i assign it to BigInt..Once it is assigned to BigInt I can use longValue to convert it into long and then parse it to get hex value..

Comment: **You can't turn that string into a long in *any* way, because it doesn't fit into a long.**

Comment: I used BigInt constructor and then converted the BigInt to long and then parsed it to get hex value..But the hex value i got is very different from the expected value...I got 9240000000000000 while I was expecting 800040000000000000....When I converted the BigInt to long it gave me value as -7908320945662590976..Why I am getting a different value and how can I resolve it..

Comment: Which part of **you can't use `long` for this** didn't you understand? I give up.

Comment: Hint: try the `toString(int)` method of `BigInteger`.

Comment: What I did is entirely different..I wrote a new method to convert a large number(it can be of any length) into its hex equivalent by using substring method and then went on appending it into the required hex string.

Answer (score 1):

Long is small for your purpose. You might want to use BigInteger object like this

```
String strBinary="100000000000000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000";
BigInteger bigInteger = new BigInteger(strBinary, 2);
System.out.println(bigInteger.longValue()); //This would give you the long value
System.out.println(bigInteger.toString(16)); //This would give you the hex string
```